# Recurisve function in a function call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm currently learning algorithms,specifically merge sort. I'm having an issue trying to understand how the code flow of this works in regards to the function call that takes two recursive functions as input. The code is as follows:

```
const merge=(left,right)=>{
    //console.log(left,right)
    let sorted=[]
    let leftIndex=0
    let rightIndex=0
    while(leftIndex<left.length && rightIndex<right.length){
        if(left[leftIndex] < right[rightIndex]){
            sorted.push(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex++
        }
        else{
            sorted.push(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex++
        }

    }
    return sorted.concat(left.slice(leftIndex).concat(right.slice(rightIndex)))

}


const mergeSort=(arr1)=>{
    if(arr1.length <= 1){
        return arr1
    }
    let mid= Math.floor(arr1.length/2)
    let left=arr1.slice(0,mid)
    let right=arr1.slice(mid)



    return merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right))


}

mergeSort(arr1)
```

Not sure exactly what happens to the array at the point where merge(mergeSort(left),mergeSort(right)) is called,does it return 2 and 4 and pass it to the merge function then return back with a sorted array array of [2,4],then do the same with the 9,10?
Thanks for any help in explaining this code flow.

Comment: `merge()` and `mergeSort()` return the array, not individual elements.

Comment: I'd like to correct the first wording you are using, maybe it's linked with your confusion: *"in regards to the function call that takes two recursive functions as input"* -> It does **not** take **functions** as input. It takes **the value returned by the function call**. Don't mix them up : if you have `function foo(int bar)`, `foo` is a function, `foo(something)` is the value returned by the function with `something` as an argument.